# scapy.srp dont give all clients

Tags: python, networking, scapy, arp

I am trying to make network scanner using scapy. But every time I run the following code it give me different result. Sometime it show me two clients and sometimes three but total clients are 5. It is not giving complete result. What's wrong? Please Help..

```
def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    answered , unanswered = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast,timeout=1)
    print(answered.summary())

scan("192.168.0.1/24")
```

Comment: If my provided answer answers this question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your timeout is too low. It's currently set to 1, so you're not currently waiting for some responses. You can also use the scapy builtin [arping](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.l2.html?highlight=arping#scapy.layers.l2.arping) to do the arp scan instead.

You can modify your code to iterate until you have found the timeout that produces the most responses:

```py
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(subnet):
    i = 0
    prev = 0
    while True:
        i+=1
        ans, unans = scapy.arping(subnet, timeout=i, verbose=0)
        num_responses = len(ans)
        print("Got {} responses in {} seconds".format(num_responses, i))
        if num_responses > prev:
            prev = num_responses
        else:
            break
    print("You should set your timeout to {} seconds".format(i-1))

scan("192.168.0.0/24")
```

Running this, we see that 4 seconds is a good timeout for my LAN (i.e. yours may be different):

```sh
$ sudo python3 arping.py
Got 3 responses in 1 seconds
Got 6 responses in 2 seconds
Got 18 responses in 3 seconds
Got 19 responses in 4 seconds
Got 18 responses in 5 seconds
You should set your timeout to 4 seconds
```